# pandas.concat with lagged inputs

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I'm working with time series data in Keras with Tensorflow as Backend.

I have a problem regarding the inputs of my Neural Network:

```
X=pd.concat([X_prices,X_os,X_months,X_wd,X_stock],axis=1)
```

and if I run:

```
print(X_prices.shape,X_os.shape,X_wd.shape,X_months.shape,X_stock.shape)
print(X.shape)
```

I get:

```
((729, 10), (729, 1), (729, 6), (729, 11), (729, 10))
((729,38))
```

Unfortunately, when appending the lagged time series:

```
X=pd.concat([X_prices,X_os,X_months,X_wd,X_stock,X_lag1],axis=1)
print(X_lag1.shape)
print(X.shape)
```

I get:

```
((729,10))
((1458,48))
```

Basically I get doubled the number of rows..

I don't know what I'm missing.

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to determine for sure without a look at the data.

But if i had to take a wild guess i would say your issue there is the index of the dataframes. Let me show you a sample of what I mean:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5), index=np.arange(5))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5), index=np.arange(5))
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5), index=np.arange(5)+5)
```

If we try to concat the first two (same index values):

```
pd.concat([df_1,df_2],1)
```

[image]

Now if we try to concat the first with the last (different index values):

```
pd.concat([df_1,df_3],1)
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, that's quite an answer: without looking at the data you figured it out!

after looking at my data I had exaclty the output with NaN, so I used the shift function in python instead of reading the lagged series from a csv (probably I messed up with indexes). 

Thank you!

Comment: thx, happened to me a couple of times thats why i had the feel for it :P